# "No rule to make target" which already exists

Tags: makefile, cmake, ros, multi-user, catkin

I'm trying to build [ROS](http://www.ros.org) from source, in an environment where I have NO root access, so no `sudo apt-get`.

`rospack` needs `libtinyxml-dev`, but I cannot just install that package. Therefore, I built TinyXML from source, installing it into `~/usr/local/{lib, include}`. Some targets (e.g. `xmlrpcpp`, `rosbuild`) build fine, but `rospack` throws a

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/home/USERNAME/usr/local/lib/libtinyxml.so', needed by 
'/home/USERNAME/ros_desktop/catkin_ws/devel/.private/rospack/lib/librospack.so'.  Stop.
```

The file `libtinyxml.so`, however, already exists and is a symlink to `libtinyxml.so.2.6.2`, which also exists.  I have absolutely no idea what to do. I tried `add_library(... SHARED IMPORTED)`, generally fiddling with `CMakeLists.txt`, but no dice. How can I just tell CMake "hey, this library exists, just link against it!" or, if the error actually means something else, get a more informative error? Why should it `make` the library if it's already there? Thanks to whoever can help me!

Content of `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(rospack)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS cmake_modules)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS filesystem program_options system)
set(Python_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS "${PYTHON_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PYTHON_VERSION_MINOR}")
find_package(PythonLibs "${PYTHON_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PYTHON_VERSION_MINOR}" REQUIRED)
find_package(TinyXML REQUIRED)

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES rospack ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES}
  DEPENDS Boost TinyXML
)

#add_definitions(-Wall)

set(API_BACKCOMPAT_V1 "YES" CACHE BOOL "Whether to enable backwards compatibility with old C++ API")
if(API_BACKCOMPAT_V1)
  add_definitions(-DROSPACK_API_BACKCOMPAT_V1)
  set(backcompat_source src/rospack_backcompat.cpp)
endif()

include_directories(include ${TinyXML_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_library(rospack
  src/rospack.cpp
  ${backcompat_source}
  src/rospack_cmdline.cpp
  src/utils.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(rospack ${TinyXML_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(rospackexe src/rospack_main.cpp)
# Set the name, and make it a "global" executable
set_target_properties(rospackexe PROPERTIES
  OUTPUT_NAME rospack
  RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX}/bin)
target_link_libraries(rospackexe rospack ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
add_executable(rosstackexe src/rosstack_main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(rosstackexe rospack ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
# Set the name, and make it a "global" executable
set_target_properties(rosstackexe PROPERTIES
  OUTPUT_NAME rosstack
  RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX}/bin)

install(TARGETS rospack rospackexe rosstackexe
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_GLOBAL_BIN_DESTINATION})
install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
  FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h")

# uninstall target
configure_file(
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake_uninstall.cmake.in"
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/cmake_uninstall.cmake"
  IMMEDIATE @ONLY)
add_custom_target(uninstall COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/cmake_uninstall.cmake)

if(CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING)
  add_subdirectory(test)
endif()

if(DOXYGEN_FOUND)
  add_custom_target(rospack-docs
    COMMAND doxygen Doxyfile
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
endif()
```

Comment: Instead of describing your code, please add it as text to your question post.

Comment: Make is not complaining about `librospack.so`.  It's complaining about `/home/USERNAME/usr/local/lib/libtinyxml.so`.  That doesn't exist, and you haven't told make how to create it, so it gives up.

Comment: I meant "The file `libtinyxml.so`, however, already exists"

Comment: I also said that it "is a symlink to `libtinyxml.so.2.6.2`", so sorry for the mistake but at least that could have been inferred haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

1. Clone everything from git repos, branch `kinetic-devel`
2. Clone TinyXML2 from https://github.com/leethomason/tinyxml2.git
3. Build TinyXML2

```
cd [TinyXML2 DIR]
mkdir build
cd !$
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$HOME/.local ..
cmake --build .
cmake --build . --target install
```

4. Symlink TinyXML2's CMake config so that rospack can find using the correct package name

```
cd $HOME/.local/lib64/cmake/tinyxml2
ln -s tinyxml2Config.cmake TinyXML2Config.cmake
```

5. Patch `rospack`'s `CMakeLists.txt` like this

```
@@ -4 +4 @@
-find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS cmake_modules)
+find_package(catkin REQUIRED)
@@ -32 +32 @@
-target_link_libraries(rospack ${TinyXML2_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
+target_link_libraries(rospack tinyxml2::tinyxml2 ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
```

6. Apply [these changes](https://github.com/ros/rospack/commit/b10a5f466b315852023bb0740bdb6cfe99982641) as the `kinetic-devel` branch does not build against TinyXML2.
7. `catkin build --cmake-args -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=$HOME/.local -- rospack`
8. `source [Catkin_Workspace]/devel/setup.bash && catkin build`